# Passing global variables from page inline script to Symfony webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, apache-flex

How to use global variables if they are defined inline on the html page? ex: `<script> var userLoggedIn= true </script>`

As per https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/331 it is recommended to export the vars needed, but I only want some dynamic variables from the Twig template.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can put your twig variables in html hidden fields.

Comment: I thought of that but some variables contain very big arrays which would be hard to add a data attr.

Comment: Did you try something like that <script> var myVar = {{ myTwigVar }} </script>

Comment: that's the example in the question.